# I don't really understand the logic of the reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays

How are we going to compare the current with accumulator when accumulator doesn't increase and still all the time in its first value (0) ? I don't get this.

```
function getMax(array) {
  return array.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    let max = current > accumulator ? current : accumulator;
    return max;
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: `return max` means that the new accumulator is `max` in the next iteration. and the 0 is his initial value

Comment: It does increase of you have an element greater than 0. Because the `max` that you return will be the `accumulator` in the next iteration, and so on.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43205019/6567275

Answer (score 4):

> Your reducer function's **returned value** is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array, and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value.

— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

---

It doesn't matter that the *variable* `accumulator` is unchanged because it is `max` that is returned.

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent `foreach` loop for `reduce`.

```js
const array = [2, 5, 4];
console.log(getMax(array));

function getMax(array) {
  let max = 0;
  array.forEach(current => {
    if (current > max) {
      max = current;
    }
  });
  return max;
}
```

Hope this will explains you more what happened in reduce.

I think you are confused because of accumulator variable used in reduce.

See this.

```js
const array = [2, 5, 4];
console.log(getMax(array));

function getMax(array) {
  return array.reduce((max, current) => {
    return current > max ? current : max;
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `0` better use `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` because otherwise your function works only if there is at least one positive number.

Comment: True. But question has 0 initial value so i have put 0 to explain. Thanks.